# Indications for improving the numbering of equations contained in a system

Tags: equations, align, subequations, ref

As you can easily see from the attached image and code, I numbered each equation manually using `\textbf`. How do you have to proceed to have a correct automatic numbering of this type with a correct alignment?

Looking at the image and the code, each equation is not called by any command of type `\eqref` or `\ref`. I was thinking about the `subequation` package but at the moment I don't know how to make it aesthetically effective. Could you cordially help me out? Thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{M1}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\overline \nabla \cdot \overline E=\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0},\,\textbf{(i)}& \quad \overline \nabla \times \overline E=-\frac{\partial \overline B}{\partial t},\,\textbf{(iii)}\\
&\overline \nabla \cdot \overline B=0,\,\textbf{(ii)}&\quad  \overline \nabla \times \overline B=\mu_0\overline J+\mu_0\varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \overline E}{\partial t}\,\,\textbf{(iv)}.\\
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}

La \textbf{(i)} si riferisce alla \textit{legge differenziale di Gauss} (e di Coulomb), la \textbf{(ii)} alla \textit{non esistenza di monopoli magnetici}, la \textbf{(iii)} alla \textit{legge differenziale di Faraday} (Henry, Lenz) e la \textbf{(iv)} alla \textit{legge di Ampere generalizzata} o di Ampere--Maxwell.
\end{document}
```

Comment: A very similar question has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449598/121799) (I'm not saying yours is a duplicate!) and, ironically, the equations were also the Maxwell equations. (My preferred solution would be to write `dF=0` and `d*F=j`, which is much easier to number and more concise. ;-)

Comment: @marmot I didn't know about this matter at all. It's yours and you certainly remember it :-). The numbering of the formulas I ask for is not based on numbers but on the bold letters i), ii), iii) and iv) with an optimal alignment of the formulas as in your previous question. You are allowed to change anything in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an option where you insert the equation numbering manually (using `\insertmanualtag{<num>}`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\newcounter{manualtag}[equation]
\renewcommand{\themanualtag}{\roman{manualtag}}%
\newcommand{\insertmanualtag}[1]{%
  \setcounter{manualtag}{\numexpr#1-1}%
  \refstepcounter{manualtag}%
  \mbox{\bfseries(\themanualtag)}%
}
\newcommand{\refmanualtag}[1]{\mbox{\bfseries(\ref{#1})}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ltxlabel}{\ltx@label}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{M1}
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      \overline{\nabla} \cdot \overline{E} &= \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}, && \insertmanualtag{1}\ltxlabel{tag1} \qquad
        & \overline{\nabla} \times \overline{E} &= -\frac{\partial \overline{B}}{\partial t}, && \insertmanualtag{3}\ltxlabel{tag3} \\
      \overline{\nabla} \cdot \overline{B} &= 0,                          && \insertmanualtag{2}\ltxlabel{tag2} \qquad
        & \overline{\nabla} \times \overline{B} &= \mu_0 \overline{J} + \mu_0 \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \overline{E}}{\partial t}. && \insertmanualtag{4}\ltxlabel{tag4}
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}

La \refmanualtag{tag1} si riferisce alla \textit{legge differenziale di Gauss} (e di Coulomb), 
la \refmanualtag{tag2} alla \textit{non esistenza di monopoli magnetici}, 
la \refmanualtag{tag3} alla \textit{legge differenziale di Faraday} (Henry, Lenz) e 
la \refmanualtag{tag4} alla \textit{legge di Ampere generalizzata} o di Ampere--Maxwell.

\end{document}
```

I've mostly updated the code to spread things out nicely, also adding alignment to the set of equations within the braced expression.

Answer (score 3):

I propose this, with some simplification of the code, and some improvements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{M1}
\begin{dcases}
  \begin{aligned}
\overline \nabla \cdot \,\overline{\!E} & =\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0} & & \textbf{(i)}& \overline \nabla \times\, \overline{\!E} & =-\frac{\partial \,\overline{\! B}}{\partial t}, & & \textbf{(iii)}\\
\overline \nabla \cdot \,\overline{\!B} & =0, & & \textbf{(ii)}&\hspace{3em} \overline \nabla \times\,\overline{\!B} & = \mu_0\,\overline{\!J\,}\!+\mu_0\varepsilon_0\frac{\partial\, \overline{\!E}}{\partial t} & & \textbf{(iv)}.\\
\end{aligned}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

La \textbf{(i)} si riferisce alla \textit{legge differenziale di Gauss} (e di Coulomb), la \textbf{(ii)} alla \textit{non esistenza di monopoli magnetici}, la \textbf{(iii)} alla \textit{legge differenziale di Faraday} (Henry, Lenz) e la \textbf{(iv)} alla \textit{legge di Ampere generalizzata} o di Ampere--Maxwell.

\end{document}
```

[image]